# Getting the path to application folder when dragging folder onto the application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an executable at C:\Users\theUser\Desktop\TheApplicaitonPath\myExecutable.exe

This application path also contains a folder, C:\Users\theUser\Desktop\TheApplicaitonPath\Configurations\config.txt

The application needs to run on various systems so I can't hard code the path to the configuration file.  I want to be able to reference the configuration file in the application with something like,

```
        string applicationLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
        //string applicationLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
        string theFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationLocation, "Configurations");
        theFilePath = Path.Combine(theFilePath, "config.txt");
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theFilePath))
        {                    //DOSTUFF
            }
```

butwhen I drag and drop a folder onto the applicaiton, I always get the path to the folder that executed the application.  In other words, if I drag a folder at,

C:\Users\theUser\Desktop\FolderToDoWorkOn

onto my executable, the following code returns the following info:

```
string applicationLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
```

returns "C:\Users\theUser\Desktop",

also

```
applicationLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
```

does the same.

How can I get the path of the .exe file that the folder was drug onto?

Comment: What does `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase` return if you *don't* pass it through `Path.GetDirectoryName()`?

Comment: Oh wow... actually System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath does return the correct path.  I had been updating the code in a .dll that is referenced in the assembly, but only recopying the .exe for testing.  In other words I wasn't changing anything during testing.  So sorry to waste anyones time. It's always the little things.

Comment: `Application.StartupPath` should also work. It'll give you the path of the folder where your application relies in, so you won't have to call `Path.GetDirectoryName()`.